# Batch: Replacing number in text (replay script) in loop

Tags: batch-file, cmd

can somebody help me with my problem, please?

I am trying to make a batch file, which will do several loops (with ANSYS commands). Problem here is that I need to change numbers in ANSYS scripts according to current loop (Results from ANSYS are always with increasing number - results01.res, results02.res etc). So in the FIRST loop I need to load to ANSYS results01.res, in SECOND loop results02.res etc, but when This "loading" is done by ANSYS script, where I need to change the number of loading file.

I found several tips for replacing text in txt file. Best of them is referenced here:
http://www.dostips.com/DtCodeBatchFiles.php#Batch.FindAndReplace
Problem is, that when I want to change number, instead of word, this is not working. Here is my batch:

```
@echo off
set /a "x=0"
set /a "y=1"

:do_while_loop_start
echo %x% loop
set /a "x=x+1"
echo %y%
set /a "y=y+1"
call rename.bat "results0%y%.res" "results0%x%.res changeNumber.txt>newfile.txt

IF %x%==20 (echo %x% equal to 20
) ELSE (
    goto do_while_loop_start
)

:do_while_loop_end
```

Comment: I don't know, what you need. Please explain and show an example of the desired output.

Comment: No idea of what you intend to achieve. You've used a batch name `rename.bat` - bad choice as `rename` or `ren` are keywords to rename. Your quotes in the `call` are unbalanced - should be in pairs, there are only 3. And unfortunately, without a listing or description of `rename.bat` we have no idea of what it does. Oh - and if the filename format uses a 2-digit numeric then what you've written will produce `results010.res ...` for `x` or `y` >=10

Comment: sorry if I am not clear enough. The rename.bat is the same batch file as I posted with link in question (batch FindAndReplace). Desired output is to "rename" result01.res to result02.res using the loop number. So if I have in script result01.res, I have to rename it to result02.res, if I have result05.res, I need result06.res. I see the first problem in script, that increasing y should be below call rename.bat. I would like to do several loops (numbered with X), renaming results with higher number by 1. Basicly, I need to rename file with higher number by one every loop. Hope I made it clear..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must note that if you do the renames in ascending order, at end *all names* will be renamed to the last name. For example:

- First loop: result01.res -> result02.res
- Second loop: previously renamed result02.res and other result02.res -> result03.res
- Third loop: all result03.res renamed to result04.res
- etc...
- In last loop: all previously renamed names -> result20.res

To solve this problem, the renames must be achieved in descending order.

On the other hand, you should *accumulate* the rename of previous cycle into the next one, otherwise the final result is the same than if just the last loop would be executed. You must move the newfile into the original one after each loop.

Finally, your code have a problem when the number have 2 digits.

```
@echo off
set /A x=120, y=121

:do_while_loop_start
   echo Rename %x:~-2% to %y:~-2%
   call rename.bat "results%x:~-2%.res" "results%y:~-2%.res" changeNumber.txt > newfile.txt
   move /Y newfile.txt changeNumber.txt
   set /A x-=1, y-=1
IF %x% gtr 100 goto do_while_loop_start
echo End of loop

:do_while_loop_end
```

Be sure to backup your original changeNumber.txt file before testing this program.

Comment: Thanks guys. **Aacini**, there is no problem with renaming all files. I am not renaming actual files, I am renaming the command in ANSYS script. This command looks somehow like this: Loadfile (C:\User...\results01.res). After this there are other commands which will produce results02.res, so before proceding to loading command again, I have to change the command in ANSYS script to load proper file - rename results01.res to results02.res and so on...And there is always just one name in script - e.g. only results02.res

Answer (score 1):

`Desired output is to "rename" result01.res to result02.res`

Look at the output what's going on and remove the `echo` and `^` if it is OK:

```
@echo off &setlocal
set /a x=0
set /a y=1

:do_while_loop_start
echo %x% loop
set /a x=x+=1
echo %y%
set /a y=y+=1
echo call rename.bat results0%x%.res results0%y%.res changeNumber.txt^>newfile.txt

IF %x%==20 (echo %x% equal to 20
) ELSE (
    goto do_while_loop_start
)

:do_while_loop_end
pause
```